# Combining Bookmarklets to create a toggle between HTTP and HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, http, url, https, bookmarklet

By searching here, I now have two bookmarklets, which switch from/to HTTP/HTTPS :-

```
javascript:location=location.href.replace(/http:/g,"https:")
```

And ...

```
javascript:location=location.href.replace(/https:/g,"http:")
```

But is there a way, please, to combine them into a single bookmarklet, which will toggle from one to the other according to whichever is presently loaded?

Answer (score 3):

This thread is a little old, but I haven't found a better answer anywhere else.

`javascript:((function(){window.location=location.href.replace(/^http/i,"https").replace(/^http\w{2,}/i,"http");})())`

is fully formed bookmarklet code that should work in any browser.

Answer (score 2):

```
location.href.replace(/^http/i,"https").replace(/^http\w{2,}/i,"http")
```

Comment: `javascript:location=location.href.replace(/^http/i,"https").replace(/^http\w{2,}/i,"http")` tested on Firefox but fails on Chrome.

Comment: @Batandwa Try something like `javascript:void(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.location.protocol == 'http:') window.location.protocol = 'https:'
else window.location.protocol = 'http:'
```

Then all you'd need to do is format that as a bookmarklet. Enjoy!