# Combining bookmarklets to create a toggle between two URL

Tags: javascript, regex, url, bookmarklet

This is basically a variant of [Combining Bookmarklets to create a toggle between HTTP and HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12068378/2114932)

I would like to combine the following two bookmarklets into one:

```
javascript:q=(document.location.href);location=location.href.replace('dp','gp/aw/d')
javascript:q=(document.location.href);location=location.href.replace('gp/aw/d','dp')
```

i.e. basically switch between two directories on a server.

This does not work (or only for one of the cases, i.e. it does not switch the 'dp' case).

```
javascript:q=(document.location.href);location=location.href.replace('dp','gp/aw/d').replace('gp/aw/d','dp');
```

Any (regex) improvements, e.g. so that the toggle will only catch the first occurrence of 'dp' in the url are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean

```
javascript:(
  function() { 
    var loc=location.href;
    loc = loc.indexOf("dp")!=-1?loc.replace('dp','gp/aw/d'):loc.replace('gp/aw/d','dp');
    location=loc;})()
```

Comment: Well, this is more code than I expected (I thought that a small adjustment to my code along the lines of the mentioned http(s) example would suffice), but it seems to do the job just fine.

Comment: Your code would change the change back immediately - also my code is using an anonymous function that is executed immediately (IIFE). It is safer than just executing statements

Comment: Code changes back: That's what I thought. And I thought that it would only need a small change.

Comment: Anonymous function: Good point. FYI, I read up on it here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way--net-18154 "Wrapping up your code neatly inside an anonymous function will make sure that there are zero naming collisions. Additionally, JavaScript noobs will be flummoxed and will think you're a god, if you're into that sort of thing." ;)

Comment: The other thing that happens in bookmarklets is `javascript:some code that returns an object` which then shows in the browser as `[Object Object]`  when run

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain to me what `loc.indexOf("dp")!=-1?` means?

Comment: that dp is NOT found in the loc string. `indexOf` will return 0-n when found, -1 when not found